# version magic mismatch error for USB Wifi adapter

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb, dmesg

My Realtek USB Wifi adapter used to work fine till a few weeks ago. 
Today I wanted to try it out but as soon as I plug it in I was getting errors in syslog and dmesg for mismatch on the version magic.

```
Here are the errors from dmesg

[275369.999797] usb 1-5: Product: Edimax AC1750 USB
[275369.999801] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Realtek
[275369.999805] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 123456
[275823.873181] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[275823.873195] 8814au: version magic '4.18.0-14-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.18.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload '


    modinfo 8814au

        name:           8814au
        vermagic:       4.18.0-14-generic SMP mod_unload 
        sig_id:         PKCS#7
        signer:         
        sig_key:        


        uname -a
        Linux penguin 4.18.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP
```

How can I change the version magic to be 4.18.0-15 or have it work without changing it ?

```
sudo modprobe 8814au
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8814au': Exec format error
```

Comment: I got it to work by removing the module under the 4.18.0-14-generic directory and re-installing and modprobe and insmod.

Comment: As usual, after updating the kernel 3d party drivers are needed to be updated too. Not a *programming* question, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. This has been asked here before with replies but no real answer. but point noted.